# Set vertical position for UILabel in UICollectionViewCell using UILayoutGuide

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uilayoutguide

I'm completely new to UILayoutGuide. I'd like to position a UILabel in the middle of the white space below the imageView, which is the superview of both imageView and UILabel (see view hierarchy below).

[image]

Normally, I would add another view and set top constraint to UIImageView and bottom constraint to the bottom edge, then center the label both horizonally and vertically to the view.

But I decided to achieve it using UILayoutGuide. Here is my code:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let topGuide = UILayoutGuide()
        let bottomGuide = UILayoutGuide()
        self.view.addLayoutGuide(topGuide)
        self.view.addLayoutGuide(bottomGuide)
        topGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: title.topAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: title.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

The result is that my UILabel does not show at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: want using storyboard or programmatically ?

Comment: There are no layout guides in Interface Builder so what is the screen shot for? Also note that the screen shot tells you your constraints are illegal.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Follow Steps -

1) Add a imageView with leading,trailing and top constraint = 0 and give aspect ratio to image so it will automatically get size according to cell

[image]

2) now add a uiView just below your imageView and give it 0 constraints as trailing, bottom, leading and 0 contraint to image bottom as shown below and make uiView colour as Clear so it won't show up

[image]

3) now drag a label in UiView and add it horizontally and vertically centre in UiView container.

[image]

and result will be as expected

Please check the following link to download xib file for collectionViewCell

```
Link - https://drive.google.com/a/erginus.com/file/d/0B2WiGVeE-REPakh3c21rWDlEWUU/view?usp=sharing
```

Comment: Link-only answers are rarely useful. It's great that you've provided something the OP can download, but that's just a comment. For your answer, would be best to provide an actual explanation (to go with your excellent screenshot).

Comment: okay let me edit the answer for full detail as you Said, thanks. so should I remove the link ? as I had used constraints which may not be easily configured by the user who had posted question. this is why I posted a link to let user download and see the answer

Comment: As I said in my question: I know how to accomplish it using dummy view with constraints in IB. I'd like to make it done using UILayoutGuides. Nonetheless, thanks for your answer